# Which countries have (or had) chess as a compulsory component of their national curricula?

Tags: history, teaching, children

The only country I know of that definitely has chess as a compulsory subject on its national curriculum is Armenia. Are there any others? I think Paraguay may be one.

Please take "national curriculum" to mean *the curriculum that is legally obligatory to be taught in all state schools*. Thus England and Wales have a national curriculum, even though there is no obligation for it to be taught either in private schools (attended by about 7% of children) or by home educators.

Quite a bit of chess is taught in Danish, Swedish, and Hungarian schools, but as far as I am aware (and I may be wrong) it is not actually a compulsory subject in any of those countries. I thought it used to be a compulsory subject in the USSR but couldn't find confirmation.

Comment: In USSR it was not.

Answer (score 3):

In [this article in the Majorca Daily Bulletin (2015)](https://www.majorcadailybulletin.com/news/local/2015/10/24/42099/spanish-schools-have-introduced-chess-class-boost-maths-learning.html), the Spanish parliament is described as having unanimously passed a resolution that year to allow regional governments to introduce chess as a compulsory or optional subject in schools. The resolution is similarly described as "non-binding" in the [Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/a7686122-524c-11e5-b029-b9d50a74fd14).

The first-mentioned article further states that

> Armenia became the first country to apply the policy nationwide in
> 2011. Mexico followed in 2014, as well as parts of China, India and Germany.

The word "parts" here implies that chess is not a compulsory part of the *national* curriculum in those countries as defined in the question. I have not yet found a fully reliable source for the case of Mexico. So far the only certain case I have identified is Armenia.

A report on the international conference on chess in schools held in Armenia in 2014 quotes FIDE's then president Kirsan Ilyumzhinov as follows:

> Recently I was in Mexico. They showed me their national school
> curricula [sic] and said that they were going to follow Armenia’s example
> and make chess a compulsory subject in schools. The same is true for
> Paraguay, Mongolia and Thailand.

Regarding Thailand, I wonder which game is being referred to. International chess is much less played in that country than makruk, also known as Thai chess.

Answer (score 2):

According to this article in the UK Telegraph newspaper - [Spain says yes to chess as game is made compulsory in schools](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/chess/11415450/Spain-says-yes-to-chess-as-game-is-made-compulsory-in-schools.html) - written in 2015 by IM Malcolm Pein who runs CSC ([Chess in Schools and Community](https://www.chessinschools.co.uk/)) in England.

There are a number of countries where something like CSC exists but, like CSC in England, it is not part of the school curriculum. Spain is the only country I know of which has made it compulsory.

Comment: But is it compulsory in Spain? According to [this article in the Majorca Daily Bulletin (2015)](https://www.majorcadailybulletin.com/news/local/2015/10/24/42099/spanish-schools-have-introduced-chess-class-boost-maths-learning.html), reporting on the same parliamentary resolution, "Spain’s parliament this year unanimously adopted a law allowing regional governments to introduce chess as a compulsory or optional subject in schools."